# How to get the evaluated value from a XSLT Variable

Tags: xml, xslt

I am doing a XML transformation using XSLT. The scenario I am stuck up with is, I have many parent elements and a child element with the same name "OtherDetails" in all the parent element. So, I iterate the parent element to get the value of child element "OtherDetails". So, I try this way.

```
<xsl:if test".='Z'">
<xsl:variable name="parent" select="concat(name(..),'/OtherDetails')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$parent" />
</xsl:if>
```

When I try a  I get the concatenated string of $parent variable but I need to get the XPath value of $parent variable.

I need to get the values of OtherDetails when the element "Other" value is 'Z'
Sample XML:

```
<structure>
<Other/>
<OtherDetails>Value1</OtherDetails>
</structure>
<power>
<Other>Z</Other>
<OtherDetails>Value2</OtherDetails>
</power>
<restrict>
<Other>Z</Other>
<OtherDetails>Value3</OtherDetails>
</restrict>
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to construct a path expression at run-time, why do you think you need to "iterate", why can't you simply use `*[Other = 'Z']/OtherDetails`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need to do is just this...

```
<xsl:variable name="parent" select="../OtherDetails"/>
```

This assumes you are positioned on an `Other` node, and want to get the `OtherDetails` under the same parent.

Note, you can also do this, but it would only work if `OtherDetails` was always following `Other`

```
<xsl:variable name="parent" select="following-sibling::OtherDetails"/>
```

Also note variables are local in scope. You would not be able to use the `$parent` outside of the `xsl:if` in your particular example.

Comment: You are correct just adding ".." before the otherdetails gave the result. Thanks Tim